# Yii2 set new active record relation on init

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have a one-to-one relationship, where there are extra fields for `Thing` in a table `ThingExtra`.

I'm trying to initialise a new `ThingExtra` to work with when creating a new `Thing`, and then save them both when `Thing` is saved:

```
class Thing extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function init(){
        if($this->isNewRecord){
            $this->extra = new ThingExtra();
        }
    }

    public function getExtra(){
        return $this->hasOne(ThingExtra::className(),['thing_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
    {
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
        $this->extra->thing_id = $this->id;
        $this->extra->save();
    }
}
```

Now when I try to create a `Thing`:

```
$thing = new Thing;
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception: Setting read-only property: Thing::extra
```

Is there anyway round this? Or is my design utterly flawed?

This approach worked pretty well for us in Yii1.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot assign a relation like this, you could try this instead :

```
public function init(){
    if($this->isNewRecord){
        $this->populateRelation('extra', new ThingExtra());
    }
}
```

Read more about [`ActiveRecord::populateRelation()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#populateRelation()-detail)

Comment: Thanks could probably get away with `null` as the second param, because presumably a new one is created anyway.

Comment: Looks like I was incorrect, and `new ThingExtra()` is required!